# finding probability distribution of sum of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, density-function

I have a probabiliy distribution $$p(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x} & x\geq0\\ 0 & x<0\end{cases}$$ I need to find the probability distribution for $Z=X+Y$ where X and Y are from the above distribution and are independent of each other.

What I did -
$$p(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)p(z-x)dx \\
p(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x}e^{-(z-x)}dx$$
Since probability distribution is for $x\geq0$ and $z-x\geq0 \implies z\geq x$ which will change our limits to $z \;\; to \;\; \infty$.
$$p(z) = \int_{z}^{\infty}e^{-x}e^{-z}e^{x}dx = \int_{z}^{\infty}e^{-z}dx$$
Now like what should I do, the x term got cancelled in the integral and the integral will go to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\geq 0\cap x\leq z$ implies that the integral will be taken from $0$ to $z$. So, it'll be
$$\int_0^z e^{-z}dx=ze^{-z},\ \ z\geq 0$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I saw the inequality in the wrong way. Inequality was meant for $x$, I saw it as for $z$ and then replaced the limits for $x$.